# What is the replacement for askConfirmation in Angular 14 Schematics?

Tags: angular, angular14, angular-schematics

How can I accomplish this in angular 14?

It seems askConfirmation is no longer exported from '@angular/cli/utilities/prompt'.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/be32c9aa34761f7ee5f6c7eafd8872e76350061d/packages/angular/cli/commands/add-impl.ts#L211

Answer (score 0):

Ended up importing from:

"@angular/cli/src/utilities/prompt";

Not the best solution, but if they don't export it, it'll have to come from src.